# Dropping Continuity Assumption of Goursat's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The following theorem and its proof comes from Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" chapter 10:

[image]

Can we drop the continuity assumption? If we do so, then $f$ will be discontinuous only at one single point $p$, which should not change the value of the integral. Here is the proof provided by Rudin:

[image]
[image]

The first part of the proof assumes that $p$ is away from the triangle so that dropping continuity won't change anything. The underlined part seems to be the only part that directly uses the continuity assumption. But how would anything change if we drop the assumption? Changing the value at one point won't change the value of the integral.

If what I am asking does not work, is there a specific counterexample? Is there an open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, a triangle $\Delta$ in $\Omega$ and a function $f$ holomorphic at $\Omega$ excluding one point and is discontinuous that point, but:

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\partial \Delta}f(z)dz \neq 0 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Well, _something_ is necessary, since $f(z)=1/z$ has non-zero integral along any simple curve enclosing $0$, after all.

Comment: holomorphic implies continuous so if $f$ holomorphic in $\Omega$ is continuous there; otherwise $f(z)=1/z$ works

Comment: @Conrad, I guess there is some ambiguity in the language "holomorphic... except discontinuous..."

Comment: boundness of $f$ is enough for example or just integrability as a line integral at $p$ - one needs to make sense of the integral of $f$ on a segment containing $p$

Comment: Thank you. I have combined your answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to conrad and paul garette. Put $f(z)=1/z$, $f(0)=100$. Put the triangle to be from $0$ to $1$ to $-1$ to $0$. The integrals on the segments does not even exist, nor to mention sum to zero. Continuity is a must in order to guarantee the existence of the integrals.